# Difference between "not remembering having said" and "never having said"?

Tags: testimony

In the context of testifying about a claim made, what is the difference between these two constructs.

- *"I never said that"*
- *"I don't remember saying that"*

You're being asked to recall something.

Comment: "That" — using a pronoun there is a terrible idea, because now you have pronoun trouble.  What is the 'that' to which you are referring? Duck or wabbit?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - The "that" is in the context of the question being asked. Conversationally, answers to questions do not need to be complete, standalone statements.

Answer (score 11):

"I don't remember saying that" is true unless you do remember and you did say that. "I never said that" is false if you said that. The former is a safer statement w.r.t. perjury (in case you actually did say that), because the prosecution would then have to prove that you did remember saying that (not impossible, but it is much more difficult to prove). Of course, the prosecution would have to prove that you did say that, to make a perjury charge stick.

Comment: Just seems a bit silly because when you make any statement about an experience, it's implicitly subject to your mental ability to recall the experience. Seems like some kind of epistemological gotcha, _"how do you know you didn't get a brain trauma in the interim and forget about the event, and the brain trauma"_

Comment: One element of perjury is thar the false statement must be made knowingly.  A witness who falsely testifies "I never said that," believing the statement to be true (whether because of a faulty memory or otherwise) does not commit perjury.

Comment: @phoog "One element of perjury is thar the false statement must be made knowingly." that's not in this answer. This answer says "Of course, the prosecution would have to prove that you did say that, to make a perjury charge stick." The prosecution would have to prove you said the statement, or that you knew you said it at the time you didn't?

Comment: The difference is, if you have proof (from other witnesses, from a recording, or whatever), that the person *did* say the thing, then "I never said that" exposed as being a lie, while "I don't remember saying that" *could* still be a truthful statement.

Comment: @EvanCarroll "that's not not in this answer": right, the comment was intended to suggest an improvement to the answer.  Details vary by jurisdiction, but knowledge that the statement is false is generally a necessary element.

Comment: @dan04 it's entirely possible for someone who has been recorded saying something to believe that they haven't said it, and the possibility increases as time passes. They might have forgotten the incident entirely or they might have thought they said something else.  They might have thought so _at the time_ -- people do sometimes substitute words in their speech, and they don't always notice.

Comment: @phoog: That's my point exactly.  In such a situation "I don't remember saying that" is a 100% true statement.  Whether they *did* say it is immaterial.

Comment: @dan04 "the person did say the thing, then "I never said that" exposed as being a lie". A lie requires intent, so in your case it doesn't necessarily mean that is a lie.

Comment: @phoog How does perjury deal with the defense of "I thought it was true at the time?" Couldnt literally everyone claim that, and wouldnt it be impossible to disprove?  To me it seems like there is either some added risk to substituting "dont remember" with "didn't"; or claims of perjury are very toothless.

Comment: @phoog I think your addition (if true) is more of a correction and that this answer is wrong as is. Maybe you should just submit it as a separate answer.

Comment: @JMac That's where rebuttal witnesses come in. Someone else testifies that they heard the witness say something to the contrary. Then the judge/jury has to decide whether it's credible that they forgot during the intervening time.

Comment: @JMac "I thought it was true at the time" is the only thing that matters.  If you testify (wrongly but truthfully according to your recollection) that you never said X, and 10 minutes later someone shows you a video of you saying X, that doesn't turn your earlier testimony into perjury.  But yes, saying "didn't" is riskier because it does make a perjury prosecution more likely to succeed.  A successful perjury prosecution for a sincere incorrect statement wouldn't be the first time a prosecutor has proved a fact contrary to reality.

Answer (score 1):

"I never said that" is not perjury if the witness believes the statement to be true because, as noted elsewhere, knowledge that the statement is false is a necessary element of perjury.  However, many people will recognize that memory is sometimes faulty, so they will say "I don't remember saying that" because they want to be careful about the assertions they're making.  This can even happen when perjury is off the table, for example in an discussion between friends or family members:

> Alice: I thought you said the library was closed.
>
> Bob: I certainly don't remember saying that.

Lawyers may encourage this approach because even though it is difficult to prove that someone knew that "I never said it" was false, it is much easier to prove than it is to prove the same of "I don't remember saying it."  After all, it's impossible for anyone other than the witness to know the witness's state of mind when they were on the stand with absolute certainty; as a result, we have various standards of proof in various contexts, and it's better to avoid having to deal with that if you can.

In other words, a prosecutor is less likely to pursue perjury charges for a "don't remember" statement, and it's to your benefit to reduce the possibility of being prosecuted even if you sincerely believe that you never uttered the statement in question.

(Of course, "I don't recall saying" might make a witness seem less credible or less reliable than "I never said," so the witness might want to take that into account, too.)